# AuthorizeNet CVV checking

Tags: php, sdk, authorize.net

I have a question about validating CVV on transactions, using Authorize.net.

Using this code.

```
    $transaction = new \AuthorizeNetAIM($loginId, $transactionKey);
    $transaction->amount = $this->_amount;
    $transaction->card_num = $this->_cardNumber;
    $transaction->exp_date = $this->_expiryDate;
```

Where do I set CVV code, for checking ? I searched the AuthorizeNetAIM class for a method but there is no one, is it done via setField() method ?

So it would be
$payment->setField('card_code', 123);

?

I mean, I read that it is's purpose is not to be used a password, but rather to detect if we are dealing with possible frauds...

Btw, I implemented that simple check which detects if count of chars is okay, based on a card type.

Comment: its `card_code` ie `$transaction->card_code`

Comment: tried that, nothing happens :\ ran it with debugger, everything seems to be assigned ($transaction->card_code = $this->_cardSecurityCode;) - in the end transaction has been aprooved even though I typed wrong cvv  :\

Comment: you need to have the cvv check enabled at authorize.net

Comment: i did enable it through their interface (it's enabled by default I saw), btw, could this be because I'm actually on the sandbox mode ? I mean, I didn't test it on real setup, just via sandbox (does authorize.net - when in sandbox mode - even make calls to banks? I don't think so)

Comment: and yeah, tnx for responding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following guide, there are certain numbers which will give you certain errors. http://developer.authorize.net/tools/errorgenerationguide/

Comment: tnx, right now I'm on another task, but I'll give it a try later, tnx a lot for helping out, I'll let you know if it helped me :)

Comment: tnx, it helped a lot!